# How handle cookies in angular 7 server side rendering

Tags: angular, cookies, angular7, server-side-rendering

I recently implemented SSR on my angular 7 project for SEO. I've been using ngx-cookie-service. I noticed an error when i first ran the app with SSR, culprit was this.cookieService.check when attempting to render the app. In one of my components I have in ngOnInit(), it performs a method call that does the following:

```
const exists = this.cookieService.check('cookiename');
if (exists) {
  showSpoilerCookieValue = this.cookieService.get('cookiename');
}
```

Temporarily i have removed the method that calls this logic to get the app to work.

How can i get this to work? Is there a better NPM package out there for cookies?

I saw posts recommending ngx-utils/cookies. However it doesn't appear to support `@nguniversal/express-engine`. There is a pull request fix this [git pull that allows express-engine](https://github.com/ngx-utils/cookies/pulls). for ngx-utils/cookies

I stupidly wasted time getting the [ngx-utils/cookies](https://github.com/ngx-utils/cookies), applying the pull, upgrading package.json with the latest angular, but didn't end up getting to test it as i ran out of time. I should have done more research before going down this path.

Is there a package cookie that will work for angular 7 SSR? im on angular 7.1 right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using

```
@ngx-utils/cookies
```

You need to check if you are in the browser or not

```
import { isPlatformBrowser } from '@angular/common';
import { CookiesService } from '@ngx-utils/cookies';
constructor(
    private cookieService: CookiesService,
    @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: Object
) {}

  isLoggedIn(): Promise<boolean> {
   return new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
    if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
      // get the cookie here
      this.cookieService.get('token')
      resolve('something here') 
    }
  });
 }
```

Hope this helps!! ... same thing if you want to use window object you will need to do

```
...
if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
    window.scrollTop() // or whatever you do with window object   
}
```

Comment: yep that did the trick. the stupid thing is, this code was already in my app.module.ts from following the SSR rendering example from the angular site. nice and simple solution.